# Meteor accounts-facebook not working on server

Tags: facebook, meteor, oauth, meteor-accounts

I have followed the this tutorial (http://bulenttastan.net/login-with-facebook-using-meteor-js/) to setup Meteors accounts-facebook package. The application worked fine while working on the local environment(localhost).

Now that I have hosted the app on my server I have the following configuration on my Facebook Apps Dashboard.

[image]

[image]

But when I try to login from my application I receive the following error message:

"URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

My app is hosted on the port '3002' so, I have set the port along with the domain name on the Site URL section on facebook and with respect to the site URL I have also set the redirect URI as given on the image.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I had a look an a app I configured a while ago, and I have actually no "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" configured and it works fine. I have "Client OAuth Login" and "Web OAuth Login" enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a Fix! Setting the ROOT_URL environment variable did the trick for me.